# Java initialization of a map embedded within another map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, initialization

Good afernoon:

I have recently created a certain class 'X' which contains a single attribute "network" which is defined as a map which uses a String as a key and another map for the value (double map). For this class, the "hashmap" implementation will be used.

The class looks approximately like this:

```
public class X {
    private Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> network;   //Attribute

    public X() {        
        network = new HashMap<>();    //An empty map is created
    }

    public int method1 {
        String string = "sentence"; 
        int number = 2; 
        String string2 = "another";
        network.put(string, <string2, number>);    //NOT WORKING - wrong syntax/wrong initialization?
    }    
}
```

However, as I execute the network.put instruction contained within the function, the compiler automatically detects an error: "Expression expected". If possible, I would like to know whether I'm using the wrong syntax when adding a new key-value element into the map or if it's the initialization of the map that's causing the error.

All help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
public class X {
    private Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> network;   //Attribute

    public X() {        
       network = new HashMap<>();    //An empty map is created
    }
    public int method1() {
      String string = "sentence"; int number = 2; String string2 = "another";
      Map<String, Integer> map = new Hashmap<>();
      map.put(string2, number);
      network.put(string, map) ; 
    }
 }
```

The idea is to create and initialize a new HashMap. Then add the key and value pair to it. Finally insert the map into the enclosing map.

Comment: Thank you so much both of you for your answers, the problem is now fixed. Have a good one.